# Advantages of using arrays.xml

Tags: android, arrays, xml, android-xml

In my application I have defined multiple string-arrays in the `strings.xml`.
What will be the advantage of moving all my string-arrays to `arrays.xml`? Is it only for a better structure? Or are there other reasons, like a better access time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filenames in `res/values/` and `res/values-.../` directories have no meaning to the OS or the build tools. You can have `<string-array>` resources in `strings.xml`, `arrays.xml`, `hey_long_filenames_are_fun.xml`, or whatever you want, so long as it ends in `.xml`. While using `arrays.xml` is a convention, it is *only* a convention.

> What will be the advantage of moving all my string-arrays to array.xml?

There may be no advantage at all. Some tools or services that process string resources (e.g., translation services) might get confused if you provide a file with mixed resource types, but that is a limitation of those tools or services, not a limitation of Android or its standard build tools.